# Working with bootstrap 4 grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

So I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image: Example]

I know I can simply create 3 equal width columns of `col-md-4`, for example, and add `Basic Card 4` with an offset, but I don't want that. Because that means, if `Basic Card 1` has more content, then `Basic Card 4` will move down, and there will be spacing between the cards on the right.

I have the following code, and I don't understand why it is being displayed like this:

[image: Wrong]

`Card 2 and 3` should be next to each other. Anyone can explain why it is behaving like this? I just want to understand it. And ofcourse, if there is a solution to what I want, by all means :)

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Basic card 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Basic card 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Basic card 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Basic card 4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it like this:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                Basic card 1<br/>
                Basic card 1<br/>
                Basic card 1<br/>
                Basic card 1<br/>
                Basic card 1<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">                    <-- Added this extra row
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Basic card 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Basic card 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Basic card 4
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```